# New database user instance created when Spring JDBC Template use calling Procedure

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

I have using Spring Mvc Jdbc template for calling procedures and functions.But the database connection is not close after the function call.Every time new database user instance create.Could anyone please give me the solution for solving this big problem.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("dbDataSource")
public DataSource dataSource;
public SimpleJdbcCall procReadData;
public PersonDTO readPersonData(Principal principal) throws SQLException {
    List<PersonDTO> personDTOList = null;
    Map<String,Object> results = null;
    procReadData = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource).withProcedureName("GET_PAWS_PERSON_DETAILS");
    procReadData.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlParameter("AV_USER_NAME", OracleTypes.VARCHAR));
    procReadData.addDeclaredParameter( new SqlOutParameter( "CUR_GENERIC", OracleTypes.CURSOR,new PersonRowMapper()));
    SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("AV_USER_NAME", principal.getName());
    results = procReadData.execute(in);
    Set<String> keys = results.keySet();
    Iterator<String> iterator = keys.iterator();


    while (iterator.hasNext()) {

        String key = (String) iterator.next();
        personDTOList = (List<PersonDTO>) results.get(key);
    }
    return personDTOList.get(0);
}
```

Database Configuration:

```
 <Resource driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" maxActive="300" maxIdle="100" maxWait="5000" name="jdbc/epaws" global="jdbc/epaws" 
        password="polusneu" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.60:1521:coeusnew" 
        username="polusneu" validationQuery="select 1 from dual"/>
```

applicationcontext.xml configuration

```
<bean id="dbDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
   <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/epaws"/>
<property name="resourceRef" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Please add some configuration, code...

Comment: @M.Deinum Added code.Please look into it

Comment: Post your configuration. One thing noticed from the code is that you don't seem to have proper tx management setup.

Comment: I added database configuration in tomcat server.xml and datasource congiguretion added in applicationcontext.xml.

Comment: Please don't add code as comments, improve your question with it. Also how do you check that the connection isn't closed?

Comment: ya,,I have added configuration.Ya I have checked in Oracle.Connection is not closing.In every transaction new instance created.

Comment: Well that is what is supposed to happen... That is the whole point of a connection pool...

Comment: But Its showing database metadata error..Too much time to load also

Comment: That isn't what you stated in your question. The connection is got from the pool and returned (your pool can contain max 300 connection so depending on the load you will have 300 open connections to oracle at some point). The error is due to the fact you are creating the `SimpleJdbcCall` over and over, you should create it once and then reuse it. Also is it actually an error or a warning/info message in the logs?

Comment: Sure.Thank you for your comments

Comment: Loading issue is still exists.and more connections are coming database connection is droped

Comment: As mentioned that is expected as that is how a connection pool works.

Comment: Is anyother way to solve this issue

Comment: Which issue? The connections aren't an issue as that is how a connection pool works...

Comment: Still same issue.after max size reached its shows exception

Comment: Now that is an issue but that isn't what you described!. As I mentioned in one of the comments you don't seem to have proper tx setup (and your configuration for jdbc, dad's and transaction manager /setup is missing all together in your question).

Comment: I have only two configuration added.One is tomcat server.xml and another one is applicationcontext.xml. I didnt any other configuration needed.Could you please guide me for that one

Comment: You should have a transaction manager and some transactional configuration. I suggest a read of the spring reference on transactions.

Comment: Sure.Thank you M.Deinum